# How to save file content into db with carriervawe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have deploy my Rails project to Heroku, and some content for my products is svg icons or images. I want to save SVG as html string into db if it is  .svg file.
Anybody has some ideas?

Comment: have you tried `carrierwave-base64`?

Comment: I need svg markup to output from db not base64 img

Comment: it does not specifically output an image. You can specify your own mime type and output decoded string to mark up that you need. 
[docs](https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64#data-format)

Comment: this 
mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader

change to this mount_base64_uploader :icon, IconUploader and still it is saving like a file

Comment: and 
where can i add mime type?

Comment: You can add Mime types in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`.

Comment: I think this is not Carrierwave related. Just read your SVG file and put it into a string: `string=open(file).read`  and then saves this string as a regular database field expression

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but it's interesting to use carrierwave or saving like a string depending which file extension i have.